# conn.open() doesn't seem to be working

Tags: c#, connection

i've dont thorough check and also been looking through forum questions regarding this but i can't seem to solve this 
This is the error : "An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL "

`public int CustomerInsert() {

```
    int result = 0;


    string queryStr = "INSERT INTO Customer(CustLoginID,CustName,CustGender,CustDOB,CustAddress,CustTelNo,CustEmail,CustPassword)"
        + "values (@CustLoginID,@CustName,@CustGender,@CustDOB,@CustAddress,@CustTelNo,@CustEmail,@CustPassword)";


    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustLoginID", this.CustLoginID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustName", this.CustName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustGender", this.CustGender);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustDOB", this.CustDOB);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustAddress", this.CustAddress);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustTelNo", this.CustTelNo);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustEmail", this.CustEmail);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustPassword", this.CustPassword);
    conn.Open();
    result += cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    return result;



}`
```

Comment: have you initialized the value for `_connStr`?

Comment: Are you getting a particular error?

Comment: @andyaldoo yes i did at the start of the class file

Comment: @Maxime yes this is the error : " An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL "

Comment: @ash the problem is likely in the connection string, as it says in the error message. "The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL". Have you ensured that the database server is running? maybe wrong credentials? or even check your internet connection